a variable ranging over type levels とはどういう意味ですか？
Dependent Type Theory - Theorem Proving in Lean 4
に

Some operations, however, need to be polymorphic over type universes. For example, List α should make sense for any type α, no matter which type universe α lives in. This explains the type signature of the function List:
#check List    -- List.{u} (α : Type u) : Type u

Here u is a variable ranging over type levels.

とありますが、「Here u is a variable ranging over type levels.」とはどういう意味なんでしょうか？
型レベル?（ここまで書かれていた内容のtype universesとは別?)
型レベル上（over）の範囲（ranging)?
型レベル上（over）の範囲（ranging)の変数(variable)?
というように型レベルからその範囲まで、急に用語が出てきた気がします（依存型では一般的な用語なのでしょうか？）。
型レベルは素朴に、深い意味はなくて、型でなんかやれますくらいのニュアンスでしょうか?
--
範囲ではなく「型レベルにわたる（ranging)変数(variable)」と訳しても、意味がわかりません。

他の質問もそうですが、何か特定の言語を指し示すタグを既に付けているのであれば、"プログラミング言語" のタグは不要です。

@cubick 今回は依存型で一般的なのかLeanの用語なのか不明なので、「プログラミング言語」を付与しています。（Leanはあくまで依存型を扱えるうちのひとつの言語くらいの認識です。なのでプログラミング言語も付与しました）

型の階層を走る変数として u を使っているという意味です。
まずプログラミング言語に限らず数学っぽい言い方をしてみます。たとえば「任意の実数 x について x²≧0」という命題があります。ここで x は変数として導入されていて、 を実数全体の集まりとしたとき x が  の要素であるならば……という話をしています。これが a variable ranging over real numbers です。
これを踏まえて Lean の話に戻ると、"u is a variable over type levels" というのは、型の階層たちのどれかになるような変数として u が使われている、ということです。
型の階層とはなんでしょうか。これは参照されているドキュメント https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/dependent_type_theory.html ではこの文のすぐ上で説明されています。つまり、Bool だとか List Nat だとか、いわゆる普通の「型」を階層 0 の型 Type 0 としたときに、その「型」の型となるようなものを Type 1 の型と呼びます。これはそのまま階層構造を作れて、Type 0、Type 1、Type 2、……と続いていきます。より具体的な例についてはドキュメントを参照してください。
そして List について考えたとき、[2, 3, 5, 7] という List Nat 型のものを考えることもあれば、より上の階層として [Bool, Nat, List Nat] という List Type 型のものを考えたくなることもあるわけです。つまり List は型の階層に対してポリモーフィックになるよう定義されていると嬉しく、これを Lean だと実現できているというのが、
#check List    -- List.{u} (α : Type u) : Type u

が示していることです。ここの u は具体的な値としては 0 とか 1 とかになります。
自分が知る限り、この "ranging over ほにゃらら" という言い方は特に Lean に限った言い方でも型理論に限った言い方でもなく、数学やコンピュータ科学分野での英語として時々使われる言い方といって良いはずです。たとえば "ranging over" の前にくる単語を論文から探すと "variables" がよく出てきます: https://hypcol.marutank.net/?q=ranging%20over&d=r
